# check if value is in range of two numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, decimal

I am trying to find the lowest value between the length and width. I then need to check if that value is between 0.01 and 0.80 but I am getting some errors on the part `<= 0.80M``in the if statement.

```
decimal min = Math.Min(Length, Width);

if(min >= 0.01M || <= 0.80M)
{

}
```

> Error 147 Invalid expression term '<='
>
> Error 148 ) expected

**Thank you everyone for the help. I know it was a simple question but I would appreciate if people stopped down voting this. I wasn't sure about something and I asked for help. I'm sure this question will be usual to someone else to**

Comment: Change it to min <= 0.80M. You need to specify the variable again

Comment: You forgot min:- `min  < = 0.80M`

Comment: `if (min >= 0.01M && min <= 0.80M)` ...

Comment: If you use `||` instead of `&&` the result will always be `true`.

Comment: I don´t see any reason for the massive amount of downvotes. The question itself seems quite clear to me (the actual problem also).

Comment: I´m voting to reopen the question. It seems pretty obvious what OP needs. He gets a compiler-error and he wrote the appropriate code. What need more to be a usefull question? Also the problem CAN be reproduced.

Comment: @HimBromBeere it's such a simple typographical error it shouldn't be asked here.

Comment: @tchrikch I don´t think it´s a typo. Its a none-understanding of the principle for chaining different operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need `&&` operator instead of `||`, Second, No need to use `M`.

Looks like you are newbie, forgive me if you are not.

`min >= 0.01 && || <= 0.80` will be true if either min is bigger or equal to 0.01 or lesser or equal to 0.80, in this case min = 9999 will also be true because it is bigger than 0.01. Hence use `&&` which will be true iff both conditions are matched.

```
decimal min = Math.Min(Length, Width);

if(min >= 0.01 && min <= 0.80)
{

}
```

Comment: i didnt down vote. but eehhm your answer that is upvoted prevents the OP to delete his question. uh :(